# Excel VBA for importing particular columns of CSV using Query

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I  have the following code below for importing a csv file. How can i modify it to import only selected columns of the csv file. (say columns 1,3 and 5 only)?

My exact requirement is how to select particular columns only when using "QueryTables.Add"

Please help. I recorded macro to import CSV. But i want to browse for the file to import. Below code asks for file and works perfect. Only i have to delete unwanted columns (vba) after importing the file.

```
Sub ImportEvents()
    Sheets("Import").Unprotect Password:="2484"
    Dim xFileName As Variant
    xFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV File (*.csv), *.csv", , "Browse the File S2KEventMsg_Table.csv", , False)
    If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Import").Select
    Dim lastRowToDel As Long
    lastRowToDel = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:E" & lastRowToDel).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range("A2"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 936
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        Columns("P:AD").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("K:N").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("D:H").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("B:B").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("B:B").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"
        Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 50
        Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 9
        Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 40
        Range("C:C").Select
        With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        Range("A:E").Select
        With Selection
        .WrapText = True
        End With
    End With
    Range("A1").Formula = "Station | Voltage Level | Equipment"
    Range("B1").Formula = "Date | Time"
    Range("C1").Formula = "Severity"
    Range("D1").Formula = "Event State"
    Range("E1").Formula = "User"
    Range("A1:E1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Bold = True
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Import").Protect Password:="2484"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Importing of Events Successful" & vbNewLine & "Goto STEP 2 or STEP 3", , "Import Successful"
    Sheets("Start").Select
    Sheets("Start").Range("H14").Select
    End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you haven't included a sample of the data you're working with; another is that your code is incomplete. (see [How to create a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

There are several ways to import CSV files into Excel, including specifying which columns you want.

It looks like you created that code by using `Developer` > <kbd>`Record Macro`</kbd> and then `Data` > <kbd>`From Text/CSV`</kbd>.

The easiest way to generate the code you need is to **do that again**, but this time <kbd>`Edit`</kbd> the import query and remove the columns you don't want.

[image: img]

To choose the columns, you just right-click the column headings that you don't want and click <kbd>`Remove Columns`</kbd>, or else select all the ones you do want, right click the column heading and and click <kbd>`Remove Other Columns`</kbd>.

[image: img]

When you have the columns laid out as you want, click <kbd>`Close & Load`</kbd> to return the data as a table.

At this point you can <kbd>`Stop Recording`</kbd> the macro and edit your code as required.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have modified my Question. My exact requirement is how to select only particular columns  when using "QueryTables.Add". Is it possible?